# get near by cities name from database

Tags: php, mysql, location, compass-geolocation

I have maxmind database for cities with longitude and latitude. I want to get cities within 50 km, 100 km and 200 km from my current location.

This is the database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `maxmind_location_city` (
  `Feature_int_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Admin1_str_code` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Country_str_code` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Feature_str_name` varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Feature_dec_lat` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Feature_dec_lon` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Feature_int_id`),
  KEY `Admin1_str_code` (`Admin1_str_code`),
  KEY `Feature_str_name` (`Feature_str_name`),
  KEY `Country_str_code` (`Country_str_code`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

SAMLE DATA:

```
INSERT INTO `maxmind_location_city` (`Feature_int_id`, `Admin1_str_code`, `Country_str_code`, `Feature_str_name`, `Feature_dec_lat`, `Feature_dec_lon`) VALUES
(146765, 'AD02', 'AD', 'Canillo', 42.567, 1.6),
(211022, 'AD02', 'AD', 'El Tarter', 42.583, 1.65),
(230839, 'AD02', 'AD', 'Meritxell', 42.55, 1.6);
```

Comment: Google "great circle distance" to get the formula.

Comment: Haversine or Vincenty are the two best known algorithms for great circle distance calculations

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP MySql and geolocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606139/php-mysql-and-geolocation)